# same name component and model in cakePhp?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, components

I have same name component and model e.g. product. So how can we use the component function and model functions?

E.g.: `$this->componentName->function()` / `$this->modelName->function()`

Comment: Can you add some more details?

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your own code I'd change the name used by your component. The way I tend to deal with this in CakePHP 2 is to use a plural naming convention with components. So in your example you would have the model `Product` and the component `ProductsComponent`. Then in your controller you can easily distinguish between the two:-

```
$this->Product->function(); // Model method
$this->Products->function(); // Component method
```

Seeing as in Cake's naming convention controllers are plural it makes sense to extend this to components.

Answer (score 0):

call the components from the collection object.

```
$this->Color->find(); // Model 
$this->Component->Color->method(); // Component
```

I ran into this problem when I had a model and component both named 
"Account". Model gets loaded after so I think it overwrites.

However, I am not sure the Component thing will work as I never tried 
it. It does work for Behaviors, so its worth a shot.

Comment: I don't believe this will work. I have just tried doing this on some code and it failed.